# How Much To "Twist" A Polygon To Match A Face On A Regular Polyhedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, platonic-solids

Suppose I want to create an icosahedron by building a set of twenty triangular pyramids (aka tetrahedrons, but see below) of an appropriate size and then rotating each into position.  I need to do three rotational transforms: the first, $\tau$, tau, around the central (X-)axis of the pyramid to get the correct "twist"; the second, $\theta$, around the Y-axis to get the correct elevation; then the third, $\phi$, around the Z-axis to get the right azimuth.  The figure below shows an example of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

As the image shows, I can find $\theta$ and $\phi$, but I can't find a way to calculate $\tau$.  (And, in fact, it's wrong in the image.)  I can keep guessing values and get close, but I'd rather have a formula so I can get it exactly.  PLUS, I'd like to be able to do the same thing with the other Platonic solids, making a formula even more necessary.

So, in a nutshell, the problem is: how to calculate $\tau$ given, say, the vertices of
a desired face and the vertices of a constructed pyramid.  (FWIW, I calculated $\theta$ and $\phi$ by calculating the centroid of the face and then converting from Cartesian to polar coordinates.)

Comment: All of these angles seem to depend on how exactly the shapes are originally oriented.  For instance, if given a nice initial orientation, then your $\tau$ is almost trivial, either $0$ or $\pi/3$, only depending on whether the target face is vertex up or vertex down, respectively.  Can you say something about your assumptions on initial orientation, both of the shapes and the axes?